# Loop through data frames and select one column in each of the data frame inside the loop using R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I would like to loop through a data frame and select an individual column from the data frame, for this I use the following code, but it gives me an error. Could someone please guide me what should be corrected in this code?

```
for (i in 1:3) {
    cur_file <- paste(i,".csv",sep="")
    curfile <- list.files(pattern = cur_file)
    rd_data[i] <- read.csv(curfile, header=F,sep="\t")
    col1 <- rd_data[i,1] # select the first column in the "1st" data frame
    n_val[i] <- rd_data[i,2] # select the second column in the each of "ith" data frame
}
```

Comment: You desired output is not clear to me, but `rd_data[i,1]` should be `rd_data[,1]` and `rd_data[i,2]` should be `rd_data[,2]` if you want to do what your comments say.

Comment: @JT85, I changed them. I get an error for the line, n_val[i] <- rd_data[,2]

Comment: Basically, all the data frames, such as rd_data[i], rd_data[2] and rd_data[3] contains the data from different .csv files. I would like to assign just the second column to a new data frame n_vals. The error which I get when I try to do this is, "Error in n_val[i] <- rd_data[, 2] : object 'n_val' not found"

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without the for loop entirely:

```
files <- list.files(pattern='*.csv')

dat <- lapply(files, read.csv, header=FALSE, sep='\t') # apply read.csv to each element of files

col_1_list <- lapply(dat, '[', 1) # use the [ function, see  ?"[" for more info.
n_val_list <- lapply(dat, '[', 2)
```

Also, your cod:

```
col1 <- rd_data[i,1] # select the first column in the "1st" data frame
```

will select the first column of each `data.frame` not just the first.

Comment: I need to store the data in each of the file in a separate data frame hence I assign them inside the loop.

Comment: This does that.  Each data.frame is stored as an element of the list `dat`.

Comment: in addition to that I just read the .csv file with names whose patten I need, hence I use it inside the loop using list.files. I would like to have individual data frame for n_vals, since I use this data frame to do further processing in the code later. Hope this makes this clearer

Comment: Then you can adjust your `pattern` argument:  `list.files(pattern='{123}.csv')`...

Comment: I don't know your file system or file structure, but I think the information contained in my answer should be enough to get you close.  Look at the results of each step individually and adjust the code accordingly.